# <video> tag. DOMException: The element has no supported sources, when not utilizing require()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html5-video

I am trying to play a video when developing locally with VueJS 2.

My code is the following :

```
<video class="back_video" :src="`../videos/Space${videoIndex}.mp4`" id="background-video"></video>
...
        data : 
            function() { 
                return {
                     videoIndex:1
                }
             }
...
const vid = document.getElementById("background-video");
vid.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
let playPromise = vid.play();

if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {
        console.log("video playing");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
This code is causing the exception given in title. Tried in several browsers, always the same.
```

If I change the src by :

```
:src="require(`../videos/Space${videoIndex}.mp4`)"
```

it works.

But in that case building time is very long as I have many different videos in my videos directory, because adding require() will force to copy all videos in the running directory at build phase (vue-cli serve), and this is really annoying. In other words I want to refer videos that are outside the build directory to avoid this (but also to avoid having videos in my git).

It is interesting to note that when I deploy server side, it works perfectly with my original code

```
 :src="`../videos/Space${videoIndex}.mp4`"
```

Note also that if i replace my code with simply

```
 src="../videos/Space1.mp4"
```

it works too. So the video itself, or its location, are not the source of the problem.

Any clue ?

Comment: Your code cannot figure out what is the `videoIndex` at build time because it's dynamic on runtime. So yeah, it will (I guess) take all of them. What do you mean by `when I deploy server side`? `src="../videos/Space1.mp4"` works well because it's hardcoded and hence there is only 1 possible file. I suppose that it's working like dynamic images and that you need the `require` anyway if you want to display something based on runtime values. Hence, there is no simple answer being hosting your video files on a CDN and pointing their location there. Or other clever hacks depending of your use-case.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your answer. Effectively you came up with the correct solution : I host my video assets on a server, and point to them in all cases. This also has the advantage to show me the real response time even in development phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your videos on a CDN to have something faster and easier to debug/work with.

Otherwise, it will need to bundle it locally and may take some time.